# Create script to reboot computers where hostnames are located in text file

Tags: java, arrays, shell, jenkins, groovy

I am trying to create a script to set off a command to restart machines where the hostnames are located in a .txt file. I am running this on Jenkins so ideally this should be in Groovy, however a shell script would work.

I have tried to use Groovy to create this code. My aim is to locate the .txt file and apply this CMD command to it

```
String fileContent = new File("C:/Users/omr/Documents/Temp/test.txt").text
println fileContent

"cmd /c shutdown -r -t 0".execute(fileContent)
```

So far Ive not had any luck, I've researched a lot how to execute cmd commands from Groovy and they all state .execute(), however I don't feel this is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to do it on Windows, try [PsShutdown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psshutdown) or [NirCmd](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/remote.html) utility to reboot the remote computer. And a batch file to cycle through your hostnames:

```bash
@echo off
for /F "tokens=*" %%A in (test.txt) do (
  echo psshutdown -r -t 0 \\%%A
)
```

I don't think Java/Groovy is really needed here, only maybe as a wrapper around shell script.

Comment: Thanks Nikita, yeah that was simple enough and I just put it round a wrapper. I guess if I wanted to do this in bash for a linux script it would be the same type of thinking. Read from file and place in to variable, then execute the restart command against the variable...

Answer (score 0):

To run remotely, you can use [psexec](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec).
To read the test file in groovy, you have the following two solutions:

```
String fileContents = new File('/path/to/file').text
```

If you need to specify the character encoding, use the following instead:

```
String fileContents = new File('/path/to/file').getText('UTF-8')
```

If you nedd a read file Line Bye Line.

```
File file1 = new File("C:\path\to\file\myTestfile.txt");
for (def i=0;i<=30;i++) // specify how many line need to read eg.. 30
{
 log.info file1.readLines().get(i)

}
```

You can also use cmd to read the text file.

```
FOR /F %i IN (file.txt) DO @echo %i
```